# if a row doesn't exist fetch it from another table

Tags: sql

I have three tables which all have a product code in common between them and the languages are the only differing variables. So the first table is all languages, the second EN and the third DE which are under the Lang column in my database.

So for the question, I'd like to simply show that if in the table "all" the product code exists with lang "EN" from the "EN" table keep that record, if not find that record but in the "DE" table with the "DE" lang code and keep that record instead.

the primary key is SAP_NO between the tables but i'm not sure how to incorporate that into the statement.

```
select 
[Qry Acc Ass Grp All SKUs].COM_CODE, 
    [Qry Acc Ass Grp All SKUs].SAP_NO, 
    [Qry Acc Ass Grp All SKUs].MANUF_CODE, 
    [Qry Acc Ass Grp All SKUs].MANUF_PART_NO, 
    [Qry Acc Ass Grp All SKUs].SHORT_TEXT_ENG, 
    [Qry Acc Ass Grp All SKUs].MAT_CLASS, 
    [Qry Acc Ass Grp All SKUs].ASSIGNMENT_GRP, 
    [Qry Acc Ass Grp All SKUs].LANG, 
    [Qry Acc Ass Grp All SKUs].DESCR

From  ([Qry Acc Ass Grp All SKUs], [Qry Acc Ass Grp EN] , [Qry Acc Ass Grp DE]

IF EXISTS    
    (
    SELECT *     
    FROM [Qry Acc Ass Grp All SKUs], [Qry Acc Ass Grp EN]    
    WHERE  [Qry Acc Ass Grp All SKUs].LANG = [Qry Acc Ass Grp EN].LANG   

    )    
ELSE
    IF NOT EXISTS
        (
        SELECT *     
    FROM([Qry Acc Ass Grp All SKUs], [Qry Acc Ass Grp DE]    
    WHERE  [Qry Acc Ass Grp All SKUs].LANG = [Qry Acc Ass Grp DE].LANG   
        )


        END;
```

Thanks in advance for your help and time!

Comment: What DMS you use? is it SQL Server? Oracle?  other?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can solve this with union. Just select both, and fetch the first one

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM (
  SELECT Column FROM Language1 -- IF NULL, THEN Language2 is first row
  UNION
  SELECT Column FROM Language2
) tbl
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server, you can do this with `cross apply`.  The query looks something like this:

```
select *
from [Qry Acc Ass Grp All SKUs] a CROSS APPLY
     (select top 1
      from ((select 'EN' as language, 1 as priority, l.* from [Qry Acc Ass Grp EN] l
            ) union all
            (select 'DE' as language, 2 as priority, l.* from [Qry Acc Ass Grp DE] l
            )
           ) l
      order priority
     ) l
```

Answer (score 0):

This is usually done using a kind of best-match with a left join:

```
select 
   sku.COM_CODE, 
   sku.SAP_NO, 
   sku.MANUF_CODE, 
   sku.MANUF_PART_NO, 
   sku.SHORT_TEXT_ENG, 
   sku.MAT_CLASS, 
   sku.ASSIGNMENT_GRP, 
   sku.LANG, 
   sku.DESCR,
   coalesce(en.column1, de.column1),-- if english exists, use it, otherwise deutsch
   coalesce(en.column2, de.column2)
From  ([Qry Acc Ass Grp All SKUs] as sku
join [Qry Acc Ass Grp EN] as en -- join english data
  on sku.LANG = en.LANG 
 and sku.SAP_NO = en.SAP_NO
left join [Qry Acc Ass Grp DE] as de -- join german data
  on sku.LANG = de.LANG   
 and sku.SAP_NO = de.SAP_NO
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont fully understand references between tables but you shoud try something like:

```
SELECT [SKUs].COM_CODE, 
    [SKUs].SAP_NO, 
    [SKUs].MANUF_CODE, 
    [SKUs].MANUF_PART_NO, 
    [SKUs].SHORT_TEXT_ENG, 
    [SKUs].MAT_CLASS, 
    [SKUs].ASSIGNMENT_GRP, 
    COALESCE([EN].LANG, [DE].LANG, [SKUs].LANG) LANG, 
    COALESCE([EN].DESCR, [DE].DESCR, [SKUs].DESCR) DESCR
 FROM [SKUs] 
 LEFT JOIN [EN] ON [EN].SAP_NO = [SKUs].SAP_NO 
 LEFT JOIN [EN] ON [DE].SAP_NO = [SKUs].SAP_NO
```

Im using:

COALESCE - to get first NON NULL value i this order EN, DE SKUs

LEFT JOIN - to not limit records in [SKUs] table if [EN] or [DE] referenced rows does not exists